# Executing a Stored Procedure on a Linked Server

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I am running SQL Server 2012 on two separate servers (let's call them Server A and Server B).  On Server A, I have created a linked server to Server B called [ServerB].  I am able to query Server B from Server A without any problems:

```
SELECT * [ServerB].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

However, when I try to execute a stored procedure:

```
EXEC [ServerB].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
```

...I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

I've done a lot of Googling and I can't seem to determine the problem.  It seems to me that this is not a "double-hop" issue.

Comment: That `Login failed` error definitely looks like a "double-hop" error.  Does `[ServerB].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]` reference yet another linked server?

Comment: @DMason Yeap, you were right...it was a "double-hop" error...I was going from Server A >> Server B >> Server A.  I assumed that going from Server B >> Server A (in the A >> B >> A sequence) didn't constitute a "double-hop" but it does.  After making Server B "trusted" for delegation, my error was resolved.  Thanks for your comment!